# Microsoft Graph - Track change of drive with delta not return who share the file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to track the change of some drives when files have been uploaded and shared, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0 & tabs = http I am using the delta request.
After some changes occur and I run the delta query, it returns the drive item of the file that the change occurs.
If I shared the file with other users, the response does not show me who shared the file, I can only find the "createdBy" which is the user who uploads the file to the drive.
My question is if it is possible to find out who shared the file?

Comment: I failed to track or an option exists to see who shared the file with track changes.

Comment: If its not available, but you want Microsoft to implement then consider filing an Microsoft user voice - so that they can consider it.